# Parse html table using file_get_contents to php array

Tags: php, html-parsing, file-get-contents

I am trying to parse the table shown [here](http://flow935.com/playlist/flowhis.HTM) into a multi-dimensional php array. I am using the following code but for some reason its returning an empty array. After searching around on the web, I found [this site](http://blog.mspace.fm/2009/10/14/parse-an-html-table-with-php/) which is where I got the parseTable() function from. From reading the comments on that website, I see that the function works perfectly. So I'm assuming there is something wrong with the way I'm getting the HTML code from file_get_contents(). Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('http://flow935.com/playlist/flowhis.HTM');

function parseTable($html)
{
  // Find the table
  preg_match("/<table.*?>.*?<\/[\s]*table>/s", $html, $table_html);

  // Get title for each row
  preg_match_all("/<th.*?>(.*?)<\/[\s]*th>/", $table_html[0], $matches);
  $row_headers = $matches[1];

  // Iterate each row
  preg_match_all("/<tr.*?>(.*?)<\/[\s]*tr>/s", $table_html[0], $matches);

  $table = array();

  foreach($matches[1] as $row_html)
  {
    preg_match_all("/<td.*?>(.*?)<\/[\s]*td>/", $row_html, $td_matches);
    $row = array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($td_matches[1]); $i++)
    {
      $td = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($td_matches[1][$i]));
      $row[$row_headers[$i]] = $td;
    }

    if(count($row) > 0)
      $table[] = $row;
  }
  return $table;
}

$output = parseTable($data);

print_r($output);

?>
```

I want my output array to look something like this:

```
1
--> 11:33AM
--> DEV
--> IN THE DARK

2
--> 11:29AM
--> LIL' WAYNE
--> SHE WILL

3
--> 11:26AM
--> KARDINAL OFFISHALL
--> NUMBA 1 (TIDE IS HIGH)
```

Comment: -1 for lack of effort. Isolate your problem instead of basically posting a huge block of code and asking people to figure out what's wrong and fix it.

Comment: This [mcve] has been destroyed by consequence of the sample input link being dead.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Don't cripple yourself parsing HTML with regexps!** Instead, let an HTML parser library worry about the structure of the markup for you.

I suggest you to check out Simple HTML DOM (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). It is a library specifically written to aid in solving this kind of web scraping problems in PHP. By using such a library, you can write your scraping in much less lines of code without worrying about creating working regexps.

In principle, with Simple HTML DOM you just write something like:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://flow935.com/playlist/flowhis.HTM');
foreach($html->find('tr') as $row) {
   // Parse table row here
}
```

This can be then extended to capture your data in some format, for instance to create an array of artists and corresponding titles as:

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');

$table = array();

$html = file_get_html('http://flow935.com/playlist/flowhis.HTM');
foreach($html->find('tr') as $row) {
    $time = $row->find('td',0)->plaintext;
    $artist = $row->find('td',1)->plaintext;
    $title = $row->find('td',2)->plaintext;

    $table[$artist][$title] = true;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($table);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

We can see that this code can be (trivially) changed to reformat the data in any other way as well.

Comment: That worked perfectly. But I need to make a multi dimensional array as shown at the bottom of the original question.

Comment: Did you check out example "Scraping Slashdot!" from the simplehtmldom site? As far as I understand it answer to that question.

Comment: Ok I added a further example, but this is as far as I will go. I will leave the rest for you to figure out.

Comment: Yes I figured it out. Thanks for the further example.

Comment: Using simplehtmldom instead of rexexps is fun, isn't it? :)

Comment: What if the html table is paginated ?

Answer (score 22):

I tried simple_html_dom but on larger files and on repeat calls to the function I am getting zend_mm_heap_corrupted on php 5.3 (GAH).  I have also tried preg_match_all (but this has been failing on a larger file (5000) lines of html, which was only about 400 rows of my HTML table.

I am using this and its working fast and not spitting errors.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();  

//load the html  
$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile("htmltable.html");  

  //discard white space   
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;   

  //the table by its tag name  
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');   


    //get all rows from the table  
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');   
  // get each column by tag name  
$cols = $rows->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('th');   
$row_headers = NULL;
foreach ($cols as $node) {
    //print $node->nodeValue."\n";   
    $row_headers[] = $node->nodeValue;
}   

$table = array();
  //get all rows from the table  
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr');   
foreach ($rows as $row)   
{   
   // get each column by tag name  
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');   
    $row = array();
    $i=0;
    foreach ($cols as $node) {
        # code...
        //print $node->nodeValue."\n";   
        if($row_headers==NULL)
            $row[] = $node->nodeValue;
        else
            $row[$row_headers[$i]] = $node->nodeValue;
        $i++;
    }   
    $table[] = $row;
}   

var_dump($table);
```

This code worked well for me.
Example of original code is here.

http://techgossipz.blogspot.co.nz/2010/02/how-to-parse-html-using-dom-with-php.html

Comment: you should do array_shift($table) because first element will be  [0] => array(0) {
  }
empty. it's because you get all tr tags in $rows including the one with th tags. I will suggest an edit.

Comment: I am using DOM with PHP 5.6.31, but found that the result of `$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('tr')` does not contain any `<td>` tags for a subsequent `$cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td')`.  Any idea why my first call to `getElementsByTagName()` appears to be stripping the HTML tags?