# Parsing a paginated HTML table in PHP

Tags: php, html, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap an HTML in PHP to locate a table and store it's value in MySQL Database using simple HTML DOM parser.

I got the reference through following [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287152/parse-html-table-using-file-get-contents-to-php-array):

Only issue i am facing is that particular HTML table has a server side pagination implemented. Any idea how to scrape such HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

Get the link of pagination from `source code` of browser

or

by right click and `copy link address`

1. the link will have **start** or **end** page no.
2. hit the link in a **loop** with changing its start or end value
3. check the response you get.
4. parse that response and insert the useful data into the database

Answer (score 0):

Check how the pagination parameters are passed when the next page is clicked and pass the same parameters to the same page to get the next page. Also find the total number of pages and use that to retrieve the content for each page