# php load JSON into variables of later DB insertion

Tags: php, json

Having trouble trans versing the array/json into the data. since the 'key' in the key/value pair is different on the parent Im at a loss of how to get it... ideally I looking to get each Hospital Name and for each hospital name get the time (08:00) element and give it a background/text color of the second element with CSS.

```
<?php

$data = '[{"name":"Anne Arundel Medical Center","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Baltimore Washington Medical Center","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Bon Secours Hospital","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Carroll Hospital Center","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Franklin Square (MedStar)","time":["01:16","","",""],"color":["background-color:#ffff00;color:#000000;",false,false,false]},{"name":"Good Samaritan Hospital\u00a0(MedStar)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Greater Baltimore Medical Center","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Harbor Hospital (MedStar)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Harford Memorial Hospital (UMUCH)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Howard County General Hospital (JHM)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Johns Hopkins Bayview Medical Center","time":["","","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Johns Hopkins Hospital","time":["","13:19","","",""],"color":[false,"background-color:#ff0000;color:#000000;",false,false,false]},{"name":"Johns Hopkins Hospital (Pediatric ED)","time":["","","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Mercy Medical Center","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Midtown (UM)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Northwest Hospital","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"R Adams Cowley Shock Trauma Center","time":["","","","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Sinai Hospital of Baltimore","time":["","","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false,false]},{"name":"St. Agnes Hospital","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"St. Joseph\u2019s\u00a0 (UM)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Union Memorial Hospital\u00a0 (MedStar)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"University of Maryland Medical Center","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]},{"name":"Upper Chesapeake Medical Center (UMUCH)","time":["","","",""],"color":[false,false,false,false]}]';
$json = json_decode($data, true);


echo '<pre>';
echo print_r($json);
echo '</pre>';
//exit;

foreach($json[?] as $item) {
    echo 'Name: ' . $item[?][1] . '<br />';
    echo 'Time: ' . $item[?][2] . '<br />';
    echo 'color: ' . $item[?][3] . '<br />';
}

?>
```

Comment: Your json array doesn't look like proper JSON encoded string

Comment: @PaulCrovella There is no key for each entry of the array, pretty unusable like this in my opinion

Comment: I'm curious on how you'd get a title, brand and description from this "data". From `$json[1]` that doesn't even seem to exist...

Comment: ok, I think this goes back to my poor codeing on a question I asked yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574672/screen-scraping-php-using-simplehtmldom - looks like I need for help on creating the json or array

Comment: @BarclayVision You can create an array with the structure you like and use `json_encode()` to turn it into json. Where does the data come from?

Comment: @jeroen see link in my previous comment...

Comment: @jeroen see results array at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574672/screen-scraping-php-using-simplehtmldom/39578427#39578427

Comment: Re worded question for clairity.... fixed JSON Data source

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON data breakdown to

```
{
   "" : [ true ],
   "00:06" : {
      "background-color:#ff6600;color:#000000;" : true
   },
   "00:11" : {
      "background-color:#ffff00;color:#000000;" : true
   },
   "00:16" : {
      "background-color:#ffff00;color:#000000;" : true
   },
   "00:17" : {
      "background-color:#ff0000;color:#000000;" : true
   },
   "01:17" : {
      "background-color:#ffff00;color:#000000;" : true
   },
   "01:30" : {
      "background-color:#ffff00;color:#000000;" : true
   },
   "02:03" : {
      "background-color:#000000;color:#ffffff;" : true
   },
   "02:37" : {
      "background-color:#ffff00;color:#000000;" : true
   },
   "03:03" : {
      "background-color:#ffff00;color:#000000;" : true
   },
   "14:44" : {
      "background-color:#ff0000;color:#000000;" : true
   },
   "Anne Arundel Medical Center" : [ true ],
   "Baltimore Washington Medical Center" : [ true ],
   "Bon Secours Hospital" : [ true ],
   "Carroll Hospital Center" : [ true ],
   "Franklin Square (MedStar)" : [ true ],
   "Good Samaritan Hospital(MedStar)" : [ true ],
   "Greater Baltimore Medical Center" : [ true ],
   "Harbor Hospital (MedStar)" : [ true ],
   "Harford Memorial Hospital (UMUCH)" : [ true ],
   "Howard County General Hospital (JHM)" : [ true ],
   "Johns Hopkins Bayview Medical Center" : [ true ],
   "Johns Hopkins Hospital" : [ true ],
   "Johns Hopkins Hospital (Pediatric ED)" : [ true ],
   "Mercy Medical Center" : [ true ],
   "Midtown (UM)" : [ true ],
   "Northwest Hospital" : [ true ],
   "R Adams Cowley Shock Trauma Center" : [ true ],
   "Sinai Hospital of Baltimore" : [ true ],
   "St. Agnes Hospital" : [ true ],
   "St. Josephs (UM)" : [ true ],
   "Union Memorial Hospital (MedStar)" : [ true ],
   "University of Maryland Medical Center" : [ true ],
   "Upper Chesapeake Medical Center (UMUCH)" : [ true ]
}
```

As you can see there is no correlation between the times and the hospitals.

Comment: maybe you can help with how I came to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574672/screen-scraping-php-using-simplehtmldom