# Format of Array using SimpleHtmlDom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Need to change the output of the array format generated by SimpleHtmlDom. my PHP code is. The results of the SimpleHtmlDom that I'm using is returning hospital names as the key not the value?:

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');

$table = array();
$html = file_get_html('https://www.miemssalert.com/chats/Default.aspx?hdRegion=3');

foreach($html->find('table#tblHospitals tr td.Chats') as $e)
{
    //echo $e->plaintext . $e->getAttribute('style') . '<hr>';
$nametime = $e->plaintext;
$color = $e->getAttribute('style');
$table[$nametime][$color] = true;
}
echo json_encode($table);

echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($table);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

current Array results:

```
array(37) {
  ["Anne Arundel Medical Center"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  [""]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  ["Baltimore Washington Medical Center"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  ["04:31"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["background-color:#ffff00;color:#000000;"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  ["Bon Secours Hospital"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    bool(true)
  }
...
```

Looking for results to be nested array by Name=>Time=>Color

```
array(37) {
  array(1) {["Name"]=>["Anne Arundel Medical Center"]=>
  array(2) {
    [time]=>[""],[color]=>[""]
  }
  } 
  array(1) {["Name"]=>["Baltimore Washington Medical Center"]=>
  array(2) {
    [time]=>["04:31"],[color]=>["background-color:#ffff00;color:#000000;"]
  } 
  }
  array(1) {["Name"]=>["Bon Secours Hospital"]=>
  array(2) {
    [time]=>[""],[color]=>[""]
  } 
  }   
...
```

Comment: You should loop over the `tr` elements, not `td.Chats`. The first `td` in the `tr` becomes the name. Then loop over the remaining `td` elements in the row to get the times and colors.

Comment: Why do you have `array(1)` for arrays that have two elements, `time` and `color`.?

Comment: corrected question, the results will be blank if no time exist, see new change - also see original post on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574672/screen-scraping-php-using-simplehtmldom

Comment: @barmar2 - I'm not sure, that is what was generated by the simplehtmldom library as results?

Comment: I meant in your desired results, you have `array(1) { [time]=>[""], [color[=>[""] }`. That should be `array(2)`. You understand that the number in parentheses is the number of elements in the array, don't you?

Comment: I don't understand your notation. You can't have two pointers like `["xxx"] => ["yyy"] => array()`. `=>` is used for the key-value relationship in an array, but there's no array for the second `=>`.

Comment: @barmar In your first comment you recommended loop `tr` but how do I set element name to `name`?

Comment: Do you want `array('name' => "Anne Arundel", 'time' => [""], 'color' => [""])`?

Comment: I need to every name (hosp. name) and get time and color from every name if it exist. End results will be JSON, but need a properly formated array first...

Comment: yes that would work as well

Comment: Or maybe you want the top-level array to be `array('Anne Arundel' => array('time' => [""], 'color' => [""]), 'Baltimore Washington Medical Center' => array('time' => ["04:31"], 'color' => "background-color:#ffff00;color:#000000;"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the rows, not the cells, so that each hospital corresponds to an element in the result array. Get the hospital name from the first `td` in the row, and the times and colors from the remaining ones in a nested loop.

```
<?php
require('simple_html_dom.php');

$table = array();
$html = file_get_html('https://www.miemssalert.com/chats/Default.aspx?hdRegion=3');

foreach($html->find('table#tblHospitals tr') as $hosp)
    {
        $tds = $hosp->find('td.Chats');
        if (!empty($tds)) {
            $name = $tds[0]->plaintext;
            $row = array('name' => $name, 'time' => array(), 'color' => array());
            foreach (array_slice($tds, 1) as $e) {
                $time = $e->plaintext;
                $color = $e->getAttribute('style');
                $row['time'][] = $time;
                $row['color'][] = $color;
            }
            $table[] = $row;
        }
    }

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($table);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: That's giving all null values?

Comment: I had a few errors. I also wasn't skipping the heading row.

Comment: That work great, thanks so much, I had no idea how to accomplish this with the SimpleHtmlDom - Thanks so much!!!